# Performance Excel VBA vs. Cálculo Multhreads

Tags: vba

Tenho uma planilha excel de 5M, porém com muitas formulas e mais de 7000 linhas de código *VBA*. Gostaria de receber informações do que posso fazer para melhor a performance. Gostaria de saber também se faz diferença usar todos os *núcleos* do processador do meu I7 ou se usar somente 2 ou 3 *núcleos* funcionaria de forma mais veloz. A impressão que dá, é que com apenas 2 núcleos, o código é mais rápido. Outra informação que gostaria de saber é se usar *64 bits* ajuda de alguma forma. Ouvi dizer que para planilhas leves é melhor continuar com *32 bits*. Meu excel é o 2010. Obrigado

Comment: Olá @Henrique, no meu limitado conhecimento de hardware, imagino que usar mais núcleos será melhor. Testei algumas planilhas tão grandes quanto em 32bit/64bit, a diferença foi mínima, obtendo melhor desempenho em 64 Com relação ao código, teria muitas dicas para repassar: 1. utilize funções com o minimo de linhas necessárias; 2.Desative a visualização; 3. Prefira utilização de With com variáveis de ambiente; 4. otimize código utilizando classes dentre outros que pode encontrar aqui: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm e http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 4):

A Microsoft implementou o conceito de Multi-threading para resolver as fórmulas de uma planilha (creio que a partir do Excel 2007). Devido a isso, se uma máquina tem mais de um core, o Excel utilizará a quantidade configurada (por padrão todos), para avaliar as fórmulas contidas numa planilha. Note, entretanto, que isso é feito apenas para a avaliação de fórmulas nativas. O mesmo não ocorre em código VBA.

Para que você consiga resolver um problema (via VBA) de maneira paralela seria necessário dividir o seu problema em várias instâncias do Excel. Como cada Excel, nesse cenário, é um processo separado, então o próprio Windows vai alocar cada Excel em um core, acelerando, portanto, a execução do código.

Entretanto, pode ser um pouco complicado fazer isso, já que primeiro é preciso verificar o que é paralelizável em seu código. Feito isso, você deve ter alguma maneira de instanciar cada Excel para que o código VBA seja executado (um script VBS pode ajudar). Depois disso, você precisa juntar o resultado.

Se o seu problema não é tão facilmente paralelizável, então não há muito o que fazer. Pode ser que VBA não seja uma boa escolha para o problema a ser resolvido.

De qualquer maneira, as dicas abaixo podem ajudar:

- Desabilitar a atualização da tela (Application.ScreenUpdating = False) enquanto o código VBA estiver sendo executado
- Colocar o cálculo das fórmulas manual (Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual) também enquanto o VBA estiver sendo executado.

Algumas referências úteis:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581868/vba-on-excel-only-use-one-processor-how-can-i-use-more

http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/05/multi-threaded-vba.html

https://superuser.com/questions/789154/excel-vba-program-only-running-at-25-speed

Answer (score 0):

Existe muitas maneiras de se fazer a mesma coisa, fórmulas normalmente deixa, as macros e planilhas mais pesadas, isso porque sempre vão ser recalculadas dependendo do caso e da fórmula.

Se suas macros são lentas tem que analisar o porque, pode ser pelas fórmulas,
interação com a planilha que tem muitas formulas se for célula por célula ocasiona lentidão.

A minha primeira solução para isso foi transferir a range a ser analisada para outra aba auxiliar apenas dados e depois passar os valores de volta
hoje em dia uso arrays para tudo

Acho que o primeiro passo é tentar otimizar essas macros, principalmente na estrutura.